# Relation between System.Buffers.dll and recycle IIS Pool

Tags: iis, buffer, pool, .net-standard-2.0, recycle

I whould like to know if there is Relation between System.Buffers.dll and Recycling IIS Pool .
In fact , I have a wcf Serive  ; that contains "System.Buffers.dll" ; When I whould like to generate PDF with "ExportToPdf" method from DevExpres , it work normaly ... but if I Recycle the IIS Pool  I have error (NetStandart version 2.0.0.0  missing ) .And If I delete  "System.Buffers.dll"  , it works normaly .....

Comment: The System.Buffers.dll provides resource pooling of any type for performance-critical applications that allocate and deallocate objects frequently. if you recycle the application pool, it will have an impact on this pool, which is why you get the error(NetStandart version 2.0.0.0 missing).

Comment: Thanks, but why I must add netsatndard.dll  ? it belongs the .Net Framework ?

Comment: [.NET Standard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard) is a formal specification of .NET APIs that are available on multiple .NET implementations. It doesn't belong .Net Framework.